# Svg using angular 2 and typescript not rendering with *ngFor

Tags: svg, angular

I'm playing around with Angular2, using typescript and there is something that is not rendering as I hoped for, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This code is working

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <svg viewBox="0 0 900 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
            <svg:circle cx=50 cy=50 r=10 />
            <svg:circle cx=71 cy=71 r=20 />
            <svg:circle cx=106 cy=106 r=30 />
        </svg>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

But when I'm trying to bind it on an object with *ngFor, it's not rendering...

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <svg viewBox="0 0 900 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
            <svg:circle *ngFor="#circle of circles"
                  [attr.cx]="circle.x"
                  [attr.cy]="circle.y"
                  [attr.r]="circle.radius" />
        </svg>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    circles = [
        {x: 50, y: 50, radius: 10},
        {x: 75, y: 75, radius: 20},
        {x: 115, y: 115, radius: 30}
    ];
}
```

I'm trying to follow this tutorial (http://teropa.info/blog/2016/02/28/metabubbles-generative-art-with-angular-2.html#drawing-svg-circles) using typescript instead ...

---

Seems to be a duplicate of [AngularJS 2 and SVG <ellipse> elements not rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042624/angularjs-2-and-svg-ellipse-elements-not-rendered)

Dom elements not generated for every iteration and properties(attributes) not generated...

---

THIS IS NOW FIXED
It works in Chrome, but not in IE 11.
IE Console was not displaying the javascript errors and chrome console was. That how I managed to fix my issue trying to solve the javascript errors I had.

I turned out to change the SystemJS config. Instead of using the following config as stated there https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#tsconfig

```
System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
```

I used it :

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: {
        emitDecoratorMetadata: true
    },
    map: {
        app: "./app"
    },
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
```

That's one part I'm not understanding very well, are those typescriptoptions are overrideing tsconfig.json file? I don't know yet... I don't know yet what is this mapping for and what are the packages, but at least I can go on with my learning

Comment: When replacing the svg elements with the div element  <div *ngFor="#circle of circles">{{circles.radius}}</div>, I can see 10, 20, 30 written on my page

Comment: What Angular version? Did you investigate the generated DOM? Is nothing generated or are some attributes missing?

Comment: "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7" and the generated dom looks like <!--template bindings={}-->
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" my-circle="">
  <circle />
 </g>

Comment: <can you try with beta.8. There was a change related to SVG AFAIR.

Comment: still the same result :(

Comment: I looked at the changelog, it seems to be a change in beta.0, nothing in beta 8, or am I missing something?

Comment: Either they did't include it in tje changelog or it hasn't landed in this version. I'm not sure if it's really related. It was about SVG namespace.

Comment: Seems to work fine https://plnkr.co/edit/elofFV?p=preview

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer IE11 doesn't work, but I managed to make it works on chrome. I had to change my SystemJS configs. The config I used was from angulario web site tutorials and it did not work, I had javascript errors in chrome console (but not in IE console) After I made my changes, the javascript errors disappeared.

Comment: I have no IE installed. There are several shims necessary for IE with TypeScript. I use only Dart where they are integrated by default. Sorry, I can't help here.

Comment: I just found https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7216. You could try adding the SVG namespace.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you! I will have a look, but I don't mind if it's not working on IE 11, I tried with Edge and it's fine.

Comment: Another way this could be done is using `<template>`. [**Check this plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mxK7enzzde36IX3UuCbA?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to angular2 but this works for me, maybe you have to add:

- `directives:[NgFor]`
- `import { NgFor } from 'angular2/common';`

sorry for my English hope it will help you.

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { NgFor } from 'angular2/common
..//
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    directives:[NgFor],
    template: `
               <svg viewBox="0 0 900 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                    <svg:circle *ngFor="#circle of circles"
                        [attr.cx]="circle.x"
                        [attr.cy]="circle.y"
                        [attr.r]="circle.radius" />
                   </svg>`
       
})
```

**Update:**

I have also tried without

- `directives:[NgFor]`
- `import { NgFor } from 'angular2/common';`

  and it works.

[image]

---

package.json info

```
..//
"license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  ..//
```

Comment: I wonder, are you also importing Component from angular2/core? I don't need to import and specify the directive for NgFor to use it with a div, I don't understand why ... but with your exemple, it's not working either...

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: @JCorriveau look my update, yes typescript, yes I import Component. I post one image.

Comment: Adding `ngFor` to directives explicitly isn't necessary since a while anymore. It's part of `PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES` which are globally available.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for clarification after realize this, did not know because it worked without NgFor, write it down to find it, and know why it works without it. Thanks to his comment I could find it quickly https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES-let.html, Thanks for everything

Comment: could it be my version of node/npm ? I use the last stable (not LTS)

Comment: I cannot figure out what's different with mine, I created a github repo with my source and config files https://github.com/JCorrivo/ng2ts_bubbles

Comment: @JCorriveau maybe this will help you https://plnkr.co/edit/4dGVMjGGVEHyZig2aLUU?p=preview

Comment: I've had a look, but even if I copy paste the code from plnkr, it's not working... that's why I created a repo with all my files and I asked about the node/npm version

Comment: @JCorriveau I do not really understand when you tell me with Node / nmp, if you're wondering if it can be so, I do not know, but you are asking me about that version I use, Node v5.4.1 , npm 3.3.12

Comment: I ask if it can be a reason... I'm not really familiar with it and when I look at plnkr, it seems to work with these config    System.config({
  //use typescript for compilation
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  //typescript compiler options
  typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
  },
  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  map: {
    app: "./src"
  },
  //packages defines our app package
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: './main.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'ts'
    }
  }
}); but that's a part I don't understand because there is so many options to configure

Comment: I made it works, first of all, it's not working in IE 11, but it is in chrome! IE 11 developper tools did not show the javascript errors since chromes did. I had to change the JSConfig to make it works, I don't know why, but the given exemple on angulario website is not working, it caused me an error. I also had an error with polyfills, but it seems to disappear when I fix the other issues.

Comment: @JCorriveau I'm glad you solve, thought to ask what browser you used ?, but then discard it. good luck

Comment: you can communicate to @GünterZöchbauer, so he knows the Error, if you want

Comment: I tried this in the latest final version of angular 2 ,it doesnt render anything in the UI

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

defining your circle component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'g[circle]',
    templateUrl: './circle.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./circle.component.scss']
})
```

**circle.component.hmtl :**

```
<svg:circle
            [attr.cx]="circle?.x" 
            [attr.cy]="circle?.y" 
            [attr.r]="radius" 

            [attr.fill]="circle?.fill"
             />
```

and your root html will be like

```
<svg>
<g circle *ngFor="let circle of circles" 
                    [attr.fill-opacity]="opacity" 
                    [attr.transform]="scale" 
                    [circle]="circle"
                     />
</svg>
```

similarly you can use all the other svg shapes by creating similar components with selector as defied above.

You can use this library which provides all the svg elements

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-svg